# How can you use ffmpeg's afftdn -sn flag to sample noise from a reference noise file?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, audio-quality, noise-reduction, noise

The FFmpeg documentation for the afftdn audio filter says for the `-sn` flag:

> **sample_noise, sn**
>   Start or stop measuring noise profile. Syntax for the command is : "start" or "stop" string. After measuring noise profile is stopped it will be automatically applied in filtering.

It's a little unclear as to the basic implementation of the start/stop values in the sample_noise -sn flag. I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.wav -af afftdn=nt=c:bn=sn=start=0=stop=1 noiseout.wav
```

as an attempt to sample the first second of sound as a noise profile, which errors with

> ```
> [afftdn @ 0x7fefbb800000] Custom band noise must be integer.
> ```

So the questions are:

1. What's the correct input format for sample_noise?
2. Is there a way to sample the noise from a noise reference `.wav` file that I have, e.g. `noiseprofile.wav`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands are instructions sent from an interface external to the filter, usually an external program using a ZMQ protocol. There is a filter that can execute commands which is what I'll use here.

Base syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i in -af "asendcmd=c='0.0 afftdn@n sn start; 1.0 afftdn@n sn stop',afftdn@n" noiseout.wav
```

To use another source for noise profile, you'll have to append it, measure noise, and then remove it.

```
ffmpeg -i in -i profile -filter_complex "[1][0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1,asendcmd=c='0.0 afftdn@n sn start; 1.0 afftdn@n sn stop',afftdn@n,atrim=1,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS" noiseout.wav
```

Above, I assume the profile is 1 second long, which is removed with atrim after denoising.

Answer (score 1):

This worked beautifully, many thanks to @Gyan.

Just to add to the accepted answer, as I needed to do this for a large number of mp3 audio files with similar noise profiles and with a naming scheme of 001_somefile.mp3. I wrote myself a batch script to do so. The `-y` confirms overwrite and the `|| pause` causes the script to halt if the command was bad. I don't know if there's any available constants to automagically obtain the length of the `noise_profile.mp3` input, so I hard-coded the 0.89 seconds length:

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`dir /B ???_*.mp3`) do (
   ffmpeg -y -i "%%f" -i noise_sample.mp3 -filter_complex "[1][0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1,asendcmd=c='0.0 afftdn@n sn start; 0.89 afftdn@n sn stop',afftdn@n,atrim=0.89,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS" "0%%f" || pause
)
```